# Painting front deck

Tags: painting

I put primer coat on my deck 2 days ago.  Today it rained most of the day. How long is it necessary to let it dry before applying the second coat of paint?

Answer (score 1):

If you primed two days ago, the first coat should be fine. So, you can put the second coat on as soon as it's dry from the rain.